# How can I filter out fictional locations (ex. "under a rock", "hiding") from Google Maps API geocode results?

Tags: json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, filtering

Google Maps API does a great job trying to locate a match for nearly every query.  But if I'm only interested in real locations, how can I filter out Google's guesses?

For example, [according to Google](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=under%20a%20rock&sensor=false), "`under a rock`" is located at "`The Rock, Shifnal, Shropshire TF11, UK`". But a person who answers the question, "Where are you?" with "Under a rock" does not mean to indicate that they are in Shropshire, UK. Instead they just don't want to tell you — well, either that or they are in real trouble, thankfully with web access, stuck under some rock.

I have several million user generated location strings that I'm attempting to find coordinates for. If someone writes "under a rock" I'd rather just leave the coordinates `null` instead of putting an obviously wrong point in Shropshire, UK.

Here are some other examples:

- [under a rock](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=under%20a%20rock&sensor=false) => Shropshire, UK
- [planet earth](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=planet%20earth&sensor=false) => Cheshire, UK
- [nowhere](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=nowhere&sensor=false) => Scituate, RI, USA
- [travelling](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=travelling&sensor=false) => Madrid, Spain
- [hiding](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=hiding&sensor=false) => Anderson, CA, USA
- [global](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=global&sensor=false) => Midland, TX, USA
- [on the web](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=on%20the%20web&sensor=false) => North Part, ON, Canada
- [internet](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=internet&sensor=false) => Frisco, TX, USA
- [worldwide](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=worldwide&sensor=false) => Mie Prefecture, Japan

Ultimately I'm after a solid way to return coordinates from a string but return false if the location is like the above.

I need to build a function that returns the following:

- [Twin Cities](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=twin%20cities&sensor=false) => Return the colloquial coordinates of Minneapolis-St. Paul
- [right behind you](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=right%20behind%20you&sensor=false) => false [Google get's this one "right" -- at least for my purposes]
- [under a rock](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=under%20a%20rock&sensor=false) => false
- [nowhere](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=nowhere&sensor=false) => false
- [Canada](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=canada&sensor=false) => Return coordinates
- [Mission District San Francisco](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mission%20district%20san%20francisco&sensor=false) => Return coordinates
- [Chicago](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=chicago&sensor=false) => Return coordinates
- [a galaxy far far away](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=a%20galaxy%20far%20far%20away&sensor=false) => false [Google also get's this "right" — zero results]

What do you recommend?

Here's a comma-delimited array for you to play at home:

```
'twin cities','right behind you','under a rock','nowhere','canada','mission district san francisco','chicago','a galaxy far far away','london, england','1600 pennsylvania ave, washington, d.c.','california','41.87194,12.56738','global','worldwide','on the internet','mars'
```

And here's the url format:

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + query + '&sensor=false'
ex: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=twin+cities&sensor=false
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually disable the guesses. Keep in mind your vague query examples are returning multiple matches, which is intended. And more generally, how do you propose determining how 'false' a match is? Your example query for `nowhere` returns multiple, valid, matches for place names called `Nowhere`; why should that return `false`?

Comment: `how can I filter out total long shots like the above?` ...thinking about this a little more: your `true` examples seem to return only single matches, so maybe build some logic off of that? Also, in the case of multiple matches, maybe you can compute the median distance between all of them? For example, `travelling` returns matches that are VERY far apart; logic could be built that returns `false` for queries that return matches that are geographically very far apart.

Comment: Yes, I understand that providing search results is the right behavior for Google.  But if I were to take a user provided string and try to identify their actual location, I'd like to ignore fictional results like the above.

Comment: "fictional results" is pretty subjective in this context. I still think it's possible for you to do this, though, but it may require you building your own logic to determine how 'real' a result is.

Comment: I agree. Trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems most of your incorrect results have a "partial_match" attribute set to "true".

e.g.

Twin Cities, no partial match:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Twin%20Cities&sensor=false

under a rock, 10+ results, all with partial match:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=under%20a%20rock&sensor=false

Though the original purpose of this attribute is not to tell wether a locality is correct or not, it's still pretty accurate on the dataset you provided.

From Google Maps API documentation:

> partial_match indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact match for the original request, though it was able to match part of the requested address. You may wish to examine the original request for misspellings and/or an incomplete address.
>   Partial matches most often occur for street addresses that do not exist within the locality you pass in the request. Partial matches may also be returned when a request matches two or more locations in the same locality. For example, "21 Henr St, Bristol, UK" will return a partial match for both Henry Street and Henrietta Street. Note that if a request includes a misspelled address component, the geocoding service may suggest an alternate address. Suggestions triggered in this way will not be marked as a partial match.

Comment: I'm testing it myself now, but this might be the winner! Thanks.

Comment: I think this is close, but not entirely trustworthy.  Given the array in the original post, your above strategy correctly flags: `under a rock` and `on the internet` (i.e. true negative). But incorrectly marks accurate (i.e. false positive): `nowhere`, `global`, `worldwide`, and `mars`. It also flags the White House (1600 Pennsylvania Ave) as a partial match (i.e. false negative). 

Confusion Matrix: [TP: 8; FP: 4; FN: 1; TN: 4] 

Can you figure out another way to distinguish between the True Positives and the False Positives?  As in, what features separate `global` and `twin cities`?

Comment: You could also check that the attribute "formatted_address" starts with your request (or that the first X characters --the length of your request-- of the formatted8address match 80% the characters present in your request)
Or that the attribute "types" is not empty AND does not contain the string "route" (depending of the degree of accuracy you have in your dataset).

Because some of these locations really exist, I think you'll have to filter the results with arbitrary conditions.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the type and route attributes as well. I think a combination of the above should get me much closer to the finish line. Thanks again.

Comment: Bounty awarded.  I may check back after implementing some of what was discussed here with a more thorough approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For anyone else approaching this question, you may also want to filter out "Route" as a type.  Nearly every false positive I've come across so far has been of this type.  This is actually more important than `partial_match` for my uses.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the direct answer to your question.

If you are currently going through 1000s of user input saved in db, and filter out the invalid ones, I think it is too late and not feasible. The output can be only good as input.

The better way is to make input as valid as possible, and end users don't always know what they want.

I would suggest you that user enter their address through [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), so that you will always have the valid address

1. User enters text, and select the suggestions
2. An marker and info window will be shown
3. When user confirms input, you save info window text as user input, not from text input.

By doing this way, you don't need to validate or filter user input.

Comment: Validate the input, not the output. +1

Comment: Obviously. However this answer assumes that accurate location information was always a priority. Instead, in this case, profile location was an area of personal expression and freedom that is only now attempting at identifying authentic location.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are Bayes Classifier implementations in javascript. Never tried them though, I currently use a Ruby implementation which works correctly.

You could have two classifications (Real and Unreal), training each of them with how many samples you want (30, 50 samples each?). "If your classifier is well trained, it will be more accurate".

Then you'd have to test the location before calling GoogleMaps API to filter Unreal locations.

Answer (score 1):

To truly succeed here you are going to have to build a database driven system that facilitates both positive and negative lookups with AI that gets smarter over time, just like Google did. I don't believe that there is a single algorithm that will filter out results based on cosmetics alone.

I looked around and found a site that contains every city in the world. Unfortunately, it doesn't give it as a single list so you'd have to spend a bit of time harvesting data. the site is http://www.fallingrain.com/world/index.html.

They seem to be using individual directories for organizing countries, states, and cities. Then, broken down further by alphabet. It is however the only comprehensive that I could find.

If you manage to get all of these locations into a database then you will have the beginnings of a positive lookup system for your queries. Also, you'll need to start building separate lists of bi, tri, and quad-city areas as well as popular destinations and land marks.

You should also store a negative lookup table for all known mismatches. People have a tendency to generate similar false data and type-o's across large populations. So, the most popular "nowhere" and "planet earth" answers will be repeated over and over again and, in every language you can think of.

One of the benefits of this strategy is that you can run relational queries against your data to get matches in bulk instead as well as one at a time. Since some false negatives will occur at the beginning then your main decision is to determine what you want to do with unmatched items. You may want to adopt a strategy where you have the ability to both reject non-matches as well as substituting partial matches with the nearest actual match.

Anyhow, I hope this helps. It is a bit of effort but if it's important it will be worth it. Who knows, you may end up with a database that's actually worth something. Maybe even a Google maps gateway service for companies/developers who need the same functionality. (:

Take care.